# OBE errors when installing windows 10 on a new pc?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I have brought a new pc that had it hard drive completely wiped so I downloaded windows 10 on to it then I run through setup but it keeps coming up with OBE errors like OOBEREGION, OOBKEYBOARD,OOBNETWORKLOSSSAVERVERSIONV2, OOBELOCAL, OOBESETTINGSMULTIPAGE.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install Windows? That shouldn't been happening - and it doesn't happen - in a proper installation done from a properly made installation USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following: ([source](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-insider/118225-insider-isos-cant-get-past-oobe-stage-2.html))

(change "newusername" and "newuserpassword" in the commands below to your own)

> [when OOBE error occurs], bring up the cmd prompt with `Shift+F10` and type:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
net user /add newusername newuserpassword
net localgroup administrators newusername /add
cd %windir%\system32\oobe
msoobe.exe
```

> [wait 15 or 20 mins to see if it continues; power off using switch if not]
>   [if it continues and gets you to the Administrator desktop]
>   log off, and log into the "newusername"
>
> run `lusrmgr.msc` and disable the Administrator account;
>
> [delete any other user account(s) (i.e. not called newusername) that were created or orphaned during the failed setup due to the oobe errors].

Comment: This is a brand new pc with no operating system so I cannot acess the admin settings.

Comment: OOBE is windows setup "out of box experience."